# The difference between ‘should be seen’ and ‘could be seen’

Tags: grammar

The Victorians used to believe that children should be seen, but not heard.

Can I replace ‘should be seen’ by ‘could be seen’?

Answer (score 2):

You need 'should'. Should conveys a requirement; could conveys an ability or opportunity. The Victorians thought that children should (=ought to be) be quiet.